# how can I open a terminal split in vim 8.1 without switching to it or going back to the previous split inside a vimscript

Tags: vim, gvim, vimscript

Basicly I want the following functionality:
Using vims new terminal functionality, I want to be able to press a button, that opens a new terminal window, without stealing focus from the file I'm editing, that compiles my code using :
"cmake -Bbuild -H. && cmake --build build/ -- -j4 -w"
that shows me the compilation live and just lets me close it again using another button when I don't need it anymore

So how can I execute a complex command using :terminal while leaving the focus in the original split?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you cant right now.
You can run one command (:ter command) or a shell (:ter), but cant put command into the open shell.
:ter cmake -Bbuild -H. && cmake --build build/ -- -j4 -w
 
will start the build but you have to go back to the other window with C-W w or C-W k or C-W j or C-W h or C-W l.
Then you can continue to type while watching the build.

```
nmap <leader> b :ter cmake -Bbuild -H. && cmake --build build/ -- -j4 -w
```

Put this into your .vimrc. If you press leader then b it will start it.
Default leader is \ if you did not change it yet.
You can do it with Tmux probably.

You can do it like this:

```
function! s:Buildit()
  ter cmake -Bbuild -H. && cmake --build build/ -- -j4 -w
  wincmd w 
endfunction
com! Buildit call s:Buildit()
nnoremap <leader> b :Buildit<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `term_sendkeys` function to reuse an open terminal window. It's a bit annoying that it requires the buffer number of the terminal, so I usually open a terminal just after I've started vim with one file. Please let me know if you figure out a way to create a keyboard mapping for the term_sendkeys function that doesn't depend on which buffer number the terminal has.

**Open a new terminal window without stealing focus:**

`:exec "vert term"|wincmd w`

**Compile in the terminal without stealing focus:**

`call term_sendkeys(2, "cmake -Bbuild -H. && cmake --build build/ -- -j4 -w \<Enter>")`.